# How to specify type of input data for Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert existing Python list into Pandas DataFrame object. How to specify data format for each column and define index column?

Here is sample of my code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1444990457000286208, 0, 286],
       [1435233159000067840, 0, 68],
       [1431544002000055040, 1, 55]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['time', 'value1', 'value2'])
```

In above example I need to have the following types for existing columns:

- time: datetime64[ns]
- value1: bool
- value2: int

Additionally time column should be used as index column.

By default all three columns are int64 and I can't find how to specify column types during DataFrame object create.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`value2` is already of the correct dtype.

For `time` you can convert to datetimes with [to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then set the index with [set_index](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.set_index).

For `value1` you can cast to bool with [astype](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html#pandas.DataFrame.astype).

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df = df.set_index('time')
df['value1'] = df['value1'].astype(bool)
```

Comment: Is this method the most optimal way? In my understanding in this way at the beginning we process data for creating DataFrame object, next we must process it again to change data type.

Answer (score 1):

<s>You can use the `dtype` keyword in the pd.DataFrame object constructor. [Docs](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame)</s>. Please see [@alex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35635248/5216568).

To use a specific column as index you can use the `set_index` method of the dataframe instance.

Comment: `dtype` kwarg is used to set dtype for entire DataFrame